Can the BGA package be centered much better if there are vias in pad for the BGA?
Can the BGA package be centered much better if there are vias in pad for the BGA?
If I have vias like this, should I fill them with solder first?


While via-in-pad can be quite useful in terms of routing, particularly for fine pitched BGAs, using exposed via-in-pad (standard vias) for BGAs is not recommended, particularly when the hole is a very large portion of the pad surface.
The issue is two-fold. When applying solder with a stencil, the solder paste doesn't tend to stay on the pad very well due to the lack of surface area or sinks into the hole once the stencil is removed leading to a reduced amount of paste for soldering.
Secondly as the board is reflowed, the solder paste and the solder from the BGA ball tend to get wicked away down the via, leading to poor or missing connections (it can completely remove the solder ball for fine pitched BGAs).
If requiring via-in-pad for a BGA, filled-via techniques should be requested during the PCB manufacture. The most common is POFV (Plated Over Filled Via). Essentially they add extra manufacturing steps whereby after drilling and plating the via holes, they fill them in with epoxy resin (or copper paste), then plate over the surface of the epoxy to form a flat pad on top. This essentially buries the via underneath a copper pad. When it then comes to soldering it is as if there is no via there at all.

If this is a one-off board DIY soldered, then you might be able to get away with trying to pre-fill the vias with solder. The hard part is making the surface of the solder "pad" flat on the BGA side. If it is raised too much your BGA device won't sit flat and again may cause failed solder joints.
Some people try just soldering to the reverse side, and partially filling the vias in the hope that this reduces the volume of solder that can be wicked away down the via. The problem here is that when the BGA is reflowed, air gets trapped within the via. During reflow the cold air expands as the board is heated up and can push through the solder paste as the solder flows leading to bubbles or poor solder joints. If the air stays trapped as it cools down applies stresses on the inside of the via which can cause the solder to crack.
In a DIY setting you generally don't have access to XRay inspection machines, so it will be very difficult to determine whether the BGA has reflowed properly and with a high-risk unfilled-via footprint it is quite likely you will have to make several attempts to get one that works correctly.

Excellent explanation! I think I wil fill the vias with solder because it's a DIY board. Not for end product use. The hole is 0.3mm in diameter for the via.

@euraad If you have spare boards, I'd try filling it from the top (BGA side). Then maybe use a hot air gun if you have it to try and level the solder out

Thank you. I opend another question about that. Se my latest question about filling a via properly after IPC 4761.
